# Import data in R (read.table)

Tags: r, import, read.table

I have the following file, which i want to import.

```
                   MONTHLY CLIMATOLOGICAL SUMMARY for MAR. 2014

NAME: larissa   CITY:    STATE:  
ELEV:    82 m  LAT:  39° 37' 39" N  LONG:  22° 23' 55" E

                   TEMPERATURE (°C), RAIN  (mm), WIND SPEED (km/hr)

                                      HEAT  COOL        AVG
    MEAN                              DEG   DEG         WIND                 DOM
DAY TEMP  HIGH   TIME   LOW    TIME   DAYS  DAYS  RAIN  SPEED HIGH   TIME    DIR
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   9.7  11.3   15:50   7.6    7:20   8.6   0.0   5.4   1.3  12.9   20:10   NNE
 2  11.8  16.9   14:50   9.8   00:00   6.5   0.0   4.2   2.7  24.1   13:30    NE
 3   9.3  11.5   14:20   7.9   00:00   9.0   0.0   6.0   0.8   9.7    3:00     N
 4  10.7  17.0   15:10   4.7    6:30   7.7   0.0   1.6   0.6  16.1   18:50    SW
 5  11.1  18.5   14:40   6.0    7:30   7.3   0.0   0.2   1.1  16.1   18:50   SSW
 6  10.9  16.9   13:50   5.1    6:30   7.4   0.0   0.0   1.1  16.1   16:20   ENE
 7  11.3  13.8   14:20  10.1    9:00   7.1   0.0   7.0   3.9  25.7    4:20   NNE
 8  12.1  16.6   14:00   9.4    8:00   6.2   0.0   2.8   1.8  22.5   22:40   ENE
 9   9.0  10.4   13:10   7.6   00:00   9.3   0.0   0.4   1.8  27.4   10:40   NNE
10   7.9  10.1   13:50   6.6   23:50  10.4   0.0   1.0   4.0  24.1   20:20    NE
11   7.8  10.1   14:20   5.4    5:30  10.6   0.0   0.8   1.1  16.1   11:00     N
12  11.3  18.7   15:30   6.8    7:10   7.0   0.0   0.0   1.3  20.9   14:20    SW
13  11.3  19.1   16:00   4.5    7:40   7.1   0.1   0.0   0.6  12.9   13:10   WSW
14  11.7  20.1   15:40   5.1    6:30   6.8   0.2   0.0   0.6  11.3   15:00   WNW
15  12.6  21.1   15:40   5.2    7:10   6.1   0.3   0.0   0.5   9.7   14:10   SSW
16  14.6  22.3   15:40   8.3    7:10   4.4   0.7   0.0   1.1  11.3   10:40   ENE
17  15.0  24.3   15:10   7.1    6:10   4.6   1.3   0.0   1.0  12.9    7:10   ENE
18  16.0  26.9   15:40   7.2    6:40   4.2   1.9   0.0   0.6  11.3   15:00   SSE
19  17.7  28.4   15:10   8.2    6:50   3.3   2.7   0.0   1.8  24.1   23:40    SW
20  16.6  22.5   16:00  11.1   00:00   2.6   0.8   0.0   2.7  24.1    7:50     N
21  13.8  21.9   16:30   6.7    6:20   5.0   0.6   0.0   0.8  16.1   14:50   ENE
22  14.3  24.1   15:40   5.8    5:40   4.9   0.9   0.0   0.5   9.7   13:50    SW
23  16.4  25.7   16:00   9.8    7:40   3.5   1.6   0.0   0.5   9.7   13:30   ESE
24  16.3  24.9   14:50  10.2    6:10   3.2   1.1   0.0   2.4  29.0   16:10   SSW
25  14.1  21.0   15:40   9.2    6:40   4.5   0.3   0.0   3.9  32.2   14:50    SW
26  12.9  19.0   16:20   9.6    6:10   5.4   0.0   1.6   1.0  12.9   12:50     N
27  14.3  19.2   13:50  11.3    2:30   4.1   0.1   0.2   3.2  33.8   14:20   ENE
28  13.1  19.0   15:40   7.4    6:30   5.3   0.0   0.4   1.4  17.7   15:50    SW
29  14.7  21.2   15:10  10.8    5:40   3.9   0.3   0.2   1.3  19.3   11:30   ENE
30  12.6  17.2   15:30   9.2   00:00   5.4   0.0   0.0   2.6  25.7    4:00   ENE
31  13.1  23.0   17:00   5.2    7:30   6.0   0.7   0.0   0.5   8.0   14:50    SW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    12.7  28.4    19     4.5    13   187.4  13.5  31.8   1.6  33.8    27     ENE

Max >=  32.0:  0
Max <=   0.0:  0
Min <=   0.0:  0
Min <= -18.0:  0
Max Rain: 7.01 ON 07/03/14
Days of Rain: 14 (> .2 mm) 5 (> 2 mm) 0 (> 20 mm)
Heat Base:  18.3  Cool Base:  18.3  Method: Integration
```

By simply trying to use `read.table` with `header=T, dec=".", sep=""` as additional arguments, i get this error:

```
Error in read.table("C:\\blablabla\\file.txt)
  more columns than column names
Execution halted
```

I think the file is not `\t` separated but rather `""`. I am also thinking this might be caused by the extra text before the table. Would `read.csv` make a difference?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the extra text before the data, but it would have been easier to try that than post a SO question.

Comment: @SQLDBA Am i supposed to preprocess my files manually and remove it? There must be a way to deal with this issue. I asked for suggestions and not for your opinion.

Comment: Make use of the `skip` parameter.

Comment: Looks like Skip is your answer but you may also want to consider a weather API like this.  http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices  In Stata you can access web services, not sure about R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the fact that there is some additional information listed above the column names. Simply skipping this will solve your issue. For this, you can use the `skip` parameter which is part of `read.csv`.

```
dat = read.csv('/path/to/file.csv', header = TRUE, dev = ".", sep = "", skip = 9)
```

Comment: i would add `n.rows = 32` in order for `read.csv` to stop parsing at the end of the table.

Comment: Note that this skips the top part of the column names that span multiple rows. You can try and recover those by hard coding them in the script (assuming that the column names do not change between files), or extract only the top part (e.g. using `readLines`) and getting the names from there.

Comment: yes i have noticed. Hard-coding won't work do. `readLines` is a good idea. There is also `colClasses` which can assign a class name at each column.

Comment: my bad `colClasses` does assign a character vector of class names to each column and it is mostly used to save import time.

Comment: for the record, `colnames(X) <- c("days", ...)` will to the trick